# Is there are correct way to print messages using list entities?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I want to know if there's a "correct" or "preferred" way to print a message using list entities.

I'm currently working through Python Crash Course 2ed and I'm at Exercise 3-4 which asks:

If you could invite anyone, living or deceased, to dinner, who would you invite? Make a list that includes at least three people you’d like to invite to dinner. Then use your list to print a message to each person, inviting them to dinner.

The code I wrote gets the job done, but it differs from the solution found online.

My code:

```
guests = ['abe lincoln', 'jesus', 'jack nicholson']

print(f"Hello, {guests[0].title()}, would you like to come to dinner?")

print(f"Hello, {guests[1].title()}, would you like to come to dinner?")

print(f"Hello, {guests[2].title()}, would you like to come to dinner?")
```

The book solution:

```
guests = ['guido van rossum', 'jack turner', 'lynn hill']

name = guests[0].title()
print(name + ", please come to dinner.")

name = guests[1].title()
print(name + ", please come to dinner.")

name = guests[2].title()
print(name + ", please come to dinner.")
```

They both produce the desired results, but is one form better to use than the other?

Comment: These solutions are not so different. they just use different string formatting/building syntax. With that said, your solution only works with Python >= 3.6 (when f-strings were introduced), the book's solution works with all versions of Python

Comment: So neither one would be more preferred than the other? I'm trying to be in the mindset of someone else going back and reading my code and it being as clean as possible.

Comment: I think you are looking at the solutions for the first edition of Python Crash Course. The online resources for the second edition are [here](https://ehmatthes.github.io/pcc_2e/).

Comment: Thank you for responding. I see what you mean, I'm guessing those exercises were left out on github for whatever reason because I also found this https://ehmatthes.github.io/pcc_2e/solutions/chapter_3/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When using lists or other iterable types, most preferred way to to loop through them, e.g:

```
guests = ['abe lincoln', 'jesus', 'jack nicholson']

for i in range(len(guests)):
  print(f"Hello, {guests[i].title()}, would you like to come to dinner?")
```

Also, in Python, the for loop can simple be used as:

```
for guest in guests:
  print(f"Hello, {guest.title()}, would you like to come to dinner?")
```

In one line:

```
for guest in guests : print(f"Hello, {guest.title()}, would you like to come to dinner?")
```

**Bonus:**

`print(f"{0}".format(argument))` can be also used to pass argument in the print function in an ordered way. Example:

```
print(f"Hello, {0}, would you like to come to dinner?".format(guest.title()))
```

Comment: If you iterate, why not `for guest in guests: print(f"Hello, {guest.title()}")`?

Comment: While you are at it, drop the index. Just iterate over the strings: `for guest in guests: ... {guest.title()} ...`

Comment: Well ofcourse, but I thought that for a beginner it is better to start off with a simpler explaintation

Comment: Thanks for the sugesstions, I am adding them

Comment: Thank you! I haven't gotten to that point in the book working with lists like that, but I had been wondering if there was a way to run the code that way. I'll keep that in mind when I get there though.

Comment: The "bonus" example does not make much sense. You would not use `{0}` and `format` when using f-strings. The whole point of using f-strings is that you can specify the variable/expression directly in the string

Comment: Yes, my motive way to introduce another way to write it.